# Resolve Transcoding Workflow

Tags: transcoding, davinci-resolve

I'm struggling to find an optimal workflow with Resolve 14 involving XAVC-S video. I need to transcode to ProRes 422 (HQ) to edit and grade within Resolve.

At present I am bringing all my source intoResolve and Media Management to transcode the footage to a directory on my media drive. I am then creating a new Resolve project and importing the transcoded footage, editing and grading.

This workflow feels a bit clunky. Is there a way of handling the transcoding within a single project?

Comment: Why the initial transcode? It's not going to do anything but degrade the footage. Unless you can't get smooth playback of the XAVC-S.

Comment: @stib XAVC-S is useless for playback. You have to transcode it.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but in Media Management, there should be an option to relink the new footage.

This should allow you use the new transcoded footage within the same project.

It's under the "+ more options" section.